# Use current date in Overpass Turbo querries

Tags: overpass-api

For example one may wish to search for roads under construction, with known opening date that is in past (in other words - one of many possible indicators that OSM data is outdated).

`[timeout:180];
(
way[highway=construction][opening_date](if:date(t[opening_date])<date("2018-2-6"))({{bbox}});
);
out body geom qt;`

query is doing it (for query on overpass see http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/vUH ), but one needs to keep date updated.

How one may use current date directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One may use `{{date}}` documented at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/Extended_Overpass_Turbo_Queries#Available_Shortcuts

Query would be

```
[timeout:180][bbox:{{bbox}}];
way[highway=construction][opening_date]
    (if:is_date(t["opening_date"]) && 
        date(t["opening_date"])<date("{{date:0 days}}"));
out geom;
```

overpass link: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/w03

Note that it allows to use also other units to specify date in past: {{date:1 day}} is replaced with the timestamp 24 hours ago. Allowed time units are: second(s), minute(s), hour(s), day(s), week(s), month(s) and year(s).

Comment: Note: once https://github.com/tyrasd/overpass-turbo/commit/ffa5dad43a65327796cb728b525e9c5b82803f1c will be released in that case one will be able to use just {{date}} instead of {{date:0 days}}

Comment: Corrections: Next version 0.7.55 requires t["opening_date"] instead of t[opening_date] to avoid a syntax error. Also added sanity check, if t["opening_date"] is really a valid date.

Comment: @mmd How behavior is changed with sanity check? I expected that date will return NaN for invalid dates and comparison with NaN will always be false.

Comment: Overpass QL is not Javascript, date comparisons are internally based on string comparisons, an invalid date is translated to a string "NaD". If you change your query a bit to check for future dates, your previous approach would hurt you badly: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/w09

Comment: @mmd So sanity checking is not affecting outcome of this particular query but in almost any other case it would be necessary?

Comment: Even though it doesn't make a difference right now, you're effectively relying on (undocumented) implementation details, which could change in the future.